How to show "Scan new card" suggestion in the Android soft keyboard for scanning payment card on click of an edit text
I have tried the conventional way of adding the autofillHint="creditCardNumber" to the EditText, however, if, for some reason, the Autofill service is disabled and this autofill option of "Scan New Card" doesn't show up.
Click here to check the screenshot

The "scan new card" option is part of autofill. So if Autofill is disabled, you won't see the suggestion.
